# JSON to Google sheet --> Strange Columns + Everything in one cell

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So far i managed to get a connection to a secure JSON. What i dont get to work is the data nice in columns. Plus in the metadata there a nice "labels" but now i get weird column names. Date: Streetname for example.

I have tried a couple of questions on this site. but i dont get it to work.

**This is my JSON data (sorry it is in dutch)(so as you can see Project: Zipcode....?):**

```
    {
      "skip": 0,
      "take": 100,
      "rows": [
{
  "Volgnummer": 1,
  "Omschrijving": "Projectnaam",
  "Omschrijving_2": "Productnaam",
  "Trailercodering": "productnaam-01",
  "Omschrijving_3": "Warehouse",
  "Datum_laden": "3 juni 2019",
  "Tijdstip_laden": "1600 - 1800",
  "Datum_aankomst_lossen": "4 juni 2019",
  "Tijdstip_lossen": "0800 - 1000",
  "Naam": "Transporteur",
  "Datum": "Straat"
  "Herkomst": huisnummer,
  "Navigatie_transport": null,
  "Project": "6644 KX",
  "Woonplaats": "Ewijk",
  "Land": "Nederland"
        },
```

**And this is my Google-Script code so far:**

```
    function pullJSON1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var url= "https://the-url.com");
  var headers = {
  
        "Authorization": "AfasToken "+ 
Utilities.base64Encode(<token><version>1</version><data> hier de 
token</data></token>)
    };

    var options = {
        "method" : "get",
        "headers" : headers 
    };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options); // get feed
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var rows = [Object.keys(dataAll)]; // Retrieve headers.
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].length; i++) {
    temp.push(dataAll[rows[0][i]]); // Retrieve values.
  }
  rows.push(temp);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); 
// Put values to Spreadsheet.
}
```

**sheet output**
[image: sheet output]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/5/322bee6375a04f52f8750659a87475eb-full.png))</sub>

**Can someone help?**

I would this rearranged in columns. Also my output in the sheet gives me 1 entry but there a 356 enterys in total.

Great thanks,
Remco

Comment: sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); is uncorrect. can we have a copy of you SS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the "skip", "take" variables? These don't fit with the tabular data, plus they seem to be part of a [pagination system](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/pagination-in-the-rest-api/) (in which case you should probably hide it from the results). Below I provide code to put the actual rows into your sheet:

```js
function pullJSON1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var url = "https://the-url.com";
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "AfasToken " + Utilities.base64Encode("<token><version>1</version><data> hier de token</data></token>");
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : headers 
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); // get feed
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var dataRows = dataAll['rows'];

  var rowHeaders = Object.keys(dataRows[0]);
  var rows = [rowHeaders]; // Retrieve headers.
  for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
    var rowData = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowHeaders.length; j++) {
      rowData.push(dataRows[i][rowHeaders[j]]); // Retrieve values.
    }
    rows.push(rowData);
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); 
  // Put values to Spreadsheet.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great. And as bonus i know now where my problem lies. And yes, if i don't use the "skip and take" i only get 10 results.

Comment: I have one question left. What i want this script to work on a specific sheet?

Comment: @RemcoEdelenbos If you want the script to run on a specific sheet, you just have to change the `var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();` to `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR_SHEETS_NAME")` (See: [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))). Alternatively, if you want to get the sheet by index rather than name, you can use [`Spreadsheet.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) and select it as you would select it from a list, i.e. `ss.getSheets()[3]`

Comment: Thank you! This is my solution